# Cambiar parámetros del web.xml en Glassfish 3

Tags: java, servidor, glassfish

Desplegué una aplicación en glassfish 3, pero me faltó cambiarle algunos parámetros al archivo web.xml.

¿Hay forma de cambiarle esos parámetros sin tener que reiniciar el servidor o desplegar nuevamente la aplicación?

Sería muy útil poder hacerlo de esa manera, ya que al reiniciar glassfish o desplegar nuevamente, afectaría a muchas personas que están utilizando la aplicación en este momento.

Comment: Hola @DavidVera, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Gracias @zeross, lo haré :)